# How can I get the session object if I have the entity-manager?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I have

```
private EntityManager em;

public List getAll(DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria)   {

    return detachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria("....").list();
}
```

How can I retrieve the session if am using entitymanager, or how can I get the result from my detached criteria?

Comment: See also `((EntityManagerImpl)em).getSession();`

Answer (score 207, accepted):

To be totally exhaustive, things are different if you're using a JPA 1.0 or a JPA 2.0 implementation.

#### JPA 1.0

With JPA 1.0, you'd have to use [`EntityManager#getDelegate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getDelegate%28%29). But keep in mind that  ***the result of this method is implementation specific*** i.e. non portable from application server using Hibernate to the other. For example [with JBoss](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2007/07/06/co-existence-with-hibernate-jpa-and-ejb3/) you would do:

```
org.hibernate.Session session = (Session) manager.getDelegate();
```

But [with GlassFish](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/05/25/be-careful-while-using-entitymanagergetdelegate), you'd have to do:

```
org.hibernate.Session session = ((org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl) em.getDelegate()).getSession();
```

I agree, that's horrible, and the spec is to blame here (not clear enough).

#### JPA 2.0

With JPA 2.0, there is a new (and much better) [`EntityManager#unwrap(Class<T>)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#unwrap%28java.lang.Class%29) method that is to be preferred over [`EntityManager#getDelegate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getDelegate%28%29) for new applications.

So with Hibernate as JPA 2.0 implementation (see [3.15. Native Hibernate API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1799)), you would do:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
...

Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

Comment: `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);` what is `Session` in `Session.class`? is it an import?

Comment: Depends on JPA implementation, if you're using eclipselink it's `org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session`

Comment: I had to put `@Transactional` on a repository class using `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)`. Otherwise, I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available`.

Answer (score 49):

See the section "***5.1. Accessing Hibernate APIs from JPA***" in the [Hibernate ORM User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-unwrap):

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
...

Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

Comment: `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);` what is `Session` in `Session.class`? is it an import?

Comment: The Hibernate Manual changed. Point 15.8 no longer gives any information about obtaining a session.

Comment: As of Jan. 2019, Hibernate current (5.3.7) manual , §5.1, still states this as the way to obtain a reference to a Session object.

Answer (score 7):

This will explain better.

```
EntityManager em = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Name.class);
```

Comment: Session class imported from where? Your mom's house? Please be specific. Don't just copy and paste

Answer (score 3):

'entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)' is used to get session from EntityManager.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class EmployeeRepository {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public Session getSession() {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    return session;
  }

  ......
  ......

}
```

Demo Application [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2020/03/spring-jpa-get-hibernate-session-object.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Hibernate 5, simply using `EntityManager.unwrap()` may not work, due to a combination of Spring's proxy behavior and recent changes in Hibernate (see [this Spring issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19577), which is fixed but not really, for details).

To make it work I had to do a double unwrap first using `null`:

```java
/**
 * Get the Hibernate {@link Session} behind the given {@link EntityManager}.
 *  
 * @see <a href="https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19577">Spring Issue #19577</a>
 */         
public static Session getHibernateSession(EntityManager entityManager) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(entityManager != null, "null entityManager");
    return ((EntityManager)entityManager.unwrap(null)).unwrap(Session.class);
}
```

I believe this is due to the handling of the proxied `unwrap()` method in Spring's `ExtendedEntityManagerCreator`:

```java
...
else if (method.getName().equals("unwrap")) {
    // Handle JPA 2.0 unwrap method - could be a proxy match.
    Class<?> targetClass = (Class<?>) args[0];
    if (targetClass == null) {
        return this.target;
    }
    else if (targetClass.isInstance(proxy)) {
        return proxy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I was working in Wildfly but I was using

```
org.hibernate.Session session = ((org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl) em.getDelegate()).getSession();
```

and the correct was

```
org.hibernate.Session session = (Session) manager.getDelegate();
```