# spring mvc hiberate, use CriteriaQuery to run select * from table where

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, criteria, hibernate-criteria

what i need is to run a sql query something like :

```
select * from table where alpahbetcolumn="A" and numbercolumn="10" and shelfcolumn="upper";
```

i want to know how to do this query in hibernate using `EntityManager`

currently this is my own try out, but not working....

```
@PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

@Transactional
    public List<Item> listItems(String alpahbet, String number, String shelf) {
        CriteriaQuery<Item> c = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Item.class);
        c.from(Item.class);
        c..where( em.equal( alpahbet, "alpahbetcolumn" ) && em.equal( number, "numbercolumn" ) && em.equal( shelf, "shelfcolumn" ));
        return em.createQuery(c).getResultList();
    }
```

i only have a very vague understanding on spring hibernate topic..still learning...
can someone please point me out how to do this sql query properly, with code example. thanks

Comment: hello, can you use HQL instead of Criteria use? for me its more readeable than criteria ;)

Comment: err, if u could provide me an code example with hql, that s fine :) i would like to learn that too

Comment: see my answer (the second one ;)) because someone answer you to create a nativequery directly, but not what you want i think ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have worked out using criteriaquery to fullfill my needs, here is the code. it works

```
 @Transactional
    public List<Item> listItems(String alpahbet, String number, String shelf) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Item> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Item.class);
        Root<Item> itemRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Item.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(itemRoot).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("alpahbetField"), alpahbet), criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("numberField"), number), criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("shelfField"), shelf));
        return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from table where alpahbetcolumn='A' and numbercolumn= 10 and shelfcolumn='upper'");
q.getResultList();
```

`createNativeQuery()` accepts plain SQL as parameter. If you expect `Item` as result, you can use this

```
em.createNativeQuery("select * from table where alpahbetcolumn='A' and numbercolumn= 10 and shelfcolumn='upper'", Item.class);
```

If you want to use JPQL (JPA Query Language), then we need your entity code to be sure, but it would be something like this

```
em.createQuery("select i from Item i where i.alphabetColumn = 'A' ");
```

For parameterized queries, use this

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from table where alpahbetcolumn=? and numbercolumn=? and shelfcolumn=?");
q.setParameter(1, "A");
q.setParameter(2, 10);
q.setParameter(3, "upper");
```

Comment: as 'A'  '10'  'upper' are variables... how do i deal with variables in this query?   replace 'A'  something like  ...+ variable +...  ?

Answer (score 1):

HQL is like this:

```
    StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    queryBuilder.append(" FROM table");
    queryBuilder.append(" WHERE alpahbetcolumn= :codeA");
    queryBuilder.append(" AND numbercolumn= :numColumn");
    queryBuilder.append(" AND shelfcolumn= :upper");

    Query query = getSession().createQuery(queryBuilder.toString());
    query = query.setParameter("codeA", "A");
    query.setParameter("numColumn", "10");
    query.setParameter("upper", "upper");


    query.list(); to get your result ;)
```

and getSession() come from :

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Required
@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

see spring configuration to configure your sessionfactory ;)

or if you use JPA try this link

[get session from entityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148231/how-can-i-get-the-session-object-if-i-have-the-entitymanager)