# What is the difference between 'getDelegate()' and 'unwrap()' for getting the Hibernate session of an entity manager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

To speed up iteration of all rows in a SQL table using Hibernate (since JPA doesn't support streaming), I followed the approach of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5182888/883073). While this works well, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151834/883073) tells us that we should retrieve the `Session` object using

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

instead of the way it was done in the answer:

```
Session session = (Session) manager.getDelegate();
```

Hower, with this change I suddenly get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available
```

The entity manager is autowired into a field in a Spring component like this:

```
@Component
public class Updater {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void update() {
        // ...
        Result loadedResult = loadAll()
        // ...
    }

    private Result loadAll() {
        Session session = (Session) manager.getDelegate();
        //Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory();
        StatelessSession statelessSession = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();

        // ... @linked answer ...
    }
}
```

As the name suggests, `loadAll` only reads data and transforms it into some `Result`. `update` does write to the database.

Note that `loadAll` is only called through `update`. Also, annotating `loadAll` with `@Transactional` doesn't fix the problem.

I know there are several other questions regarding this error, stating `@Transactional` to be the answer. My question is what the difference between `getDelegate` and `unwrap` really is: Why does the one fail and the other not? (And why doesn't `@Transactional` fix the problem?)

I'm using H2 1.4.190 and Hibernate 4.3.11.Final (through Spring Boot 1.3.2.RELEASE).

**EDIT** Full minimal example (with package declarations and imports omitted). All classes are in package `com.example`:

*Entity.java*

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;

    public int value;
}
```

*EntityRepository.java*

```
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer> {
}
```

*Config.java*:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EntityScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {
}
```

*Runner.java*:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Runner.class);
        application.setWebEnvironment(false);
        application.run(args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private Updater updater;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        updater.insert(1, 4, 2);
        updater.update();

        updater.printAll();
    }
}
```

*Updater.java*:

```
@Component
public class Updater {

    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository repository;

    @PersistenceContext //@Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void insert(int... values) {
        for (int value : values) {
            Entity entity = new Entity();
            entity.value = value;
            repository.save(entity);
        }
        repository.flush();
    }

    public void update() {
        // Call "transactioned" method through an intermediary method.
        // The code works if 'Runner' calls 'transactionedUpdate' directly.
        transactionedUpdate();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void transactionedUpdate() {
        int sum = loadAll();

        // Set all 'value's to 'sum'.
        List<Entity> entities = repository.findAll();
        for (Entity entity : entities) {
            entity.value = sum;
            repository.save(entity);
        }
        repository.flush();
    }

    public int loadAll() {
//        Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory();
        StatelessSession statelessSession = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();

        Query query = statelessSession.createQuery("FROM com.example.Entity e");
        query.setFetchSize(1000);
        query.setReadOnly(true);
        query.setLockMode("e", LockMode.NONE);
        ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

        int sum = 0;
        while (results.next()) {
            Entity entity = (Entity) results.get(0);
            sum += entity.value;
        }

        results.close();
        statelessSession.close();

        return sum;
    }

    public void printAll() {
        List<Entity> entities = repository.findAll();
        for (Entity entity : entities) {
            System.out.println(entity.id + ": " + entity.value);
        }
    }
}
```

*application.yml*:

```
spring:
    jpa:
        open-in-view: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
            naming-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringNamingStrategy
        database: H2
        show_sql: false
        properties:
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
        url: jdbc:h2:file:~/data-test/db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
        name:
        username: test
        password:
```

*Stack trace*:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:809) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:777) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.Runner.main(Runner.java:16) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:268) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.unwrap(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.Updater.loadAll(Updater.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.Updater.doUpdate(Updater.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.Updater.update(Updater.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.Updater$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$503dcdb8.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:651) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.Updater$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f362c2c8.update(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.Runner.run(Runner.java:25) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Don't use `@Autowired` use `@PersistenceContext` when injecting an `EntityManager`.

Comment: While this does remove IntelliJ's "Could not autowire..." inspection error, it doesn't change the observed behavior.

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Comment: update() method is not annotated with @Transactional ?

Comment: Your methods aren't `@Transactional` so no transaction. This is also clear from your stakctrace as there is no transactional proxy for the `Updater`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that in the example (which indeed works if `update` is `@Transactional`). I have updated the example to be more like the original code. The difference is that the "transactioned" method is called through an intermediary method. But why does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not using Spring, but when I wanted to get the SessionFactory for performance reasons I simply declared it in a `Stateless` EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class OpinionViewCache {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="opee") SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private StatelessSession statelessSession;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
```

And to get session I used a simple call:

```
statelessSession = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
```

Closed it when I was done:

```
statelessSession.close();
```

Otherwise the code I used for testing from Java SE was pretty straight forward:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("opjpa");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
EntityManagerImpl emImpl = (EntityManagerImpl)em;
HibernateEntityManagerFactory factory = emImpl.getFactory();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = factory.getSessionFactory();
```